# The letter 'i' in small capital, boldface and italic with "newpxtext"

Tags: fonts, fontspec

Using `newpxtext` under an Unicode engine. With `\scshape\bfseries\itshape`, the lowercased `i` becomes

[image]

while with `\scshape\itshape` it is simply

[image]

as expected. Is this by design or is this a bug? Is there some way to get the dotless "***I***" when it is in boldface?

Below is a MWE. To reproduce the problem, one needs to compile it with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. Some alternative methods are added for comparison, you can uncomment them to replace `\usepackage{newpxtext}` to see the effect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}

% \usepackage[type1]{newpxtext}

% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}

% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage{tgpagella}

\begin{document}

abcdefghijk

{\scshape\itshape i \i}

{\scshape\bfseries\itshape i \i}

{\scshape\bfseries i \i}

\end{document}
```

Expected result:

[image]

Current result:

[image]

Comment: Not bug. Use `\usepackage[type1]{newpxtext}` with unicode engines.

Comment: @hair-splitter Thank you. I checked the code, the option `type1` simply does `\zpl@otffalse`, thus behaves the same as using pdfLaTeX. The 'bug' is in the `.otf` file.

Comment: Workaround might be to use `tgpagella` or `domitian`.

Comment: @Davislor Not sure if I'm using them correctly, but `tgpagella` and `domitian` do not seem to support the combination of `\scshape`+`\itshape`/`\bfseries`.

Comment: Domitian indeed seems not to, at least in the Type 1 version. teX Gyre Pagella, however, supports the font faces `{T1}{qpl}{scit}{b}` or `{T1}{qpl}{scit}{bx}`. You might need to load `\usepackage{fontaxes}`.

Answer (score 6):

I did `\showtokens\expandafter{\fontname\font}` before the closing brace in the line that produces the suspect output. The answer on the console is

```
> "[TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldItalic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;-ss05;+tnum;+lnum;+smcp;+pcap;mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt.
```

So I prepared a test file for plain XeTeX

```
\font\testit="[TeXGyrePagellaX-Italic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;-ss05;+tnum;+lnum;+smcp;+pcap;mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt
\font\testbf="[TeXGyrePagellaX-Bold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;-ss05;+tnum;+lnum;+smcp;+pcap;mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt
\font\testbfit="[TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldItalic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;-ss05;+tnum;+lnum;+smcp;+pcap;mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt

\testit
aiqRr

\testbf
aiqRr

\testbfit
aiqRr

\bye
```

and the output is

[image]

Sorry, bug. If I change `language=dflt` into `language=TRK` in the `\testbfit` line, I get

[image]

This shows that the font maintainers have mixed things up, because with `language=TRK` the dot should appear.

Comment: To add to the list, there is no small caps “dotless i” in any variant.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, is it possible to select the `language` with the key `RawFeature` of `fontspec`? I tried to set `script=latn;language=dflt;-ss05;+tnum;+lnum;+smcp;+pcap;mapping=tex-text` as the `RawFeature`, which seems to work fine, but with `language=TRK`, the small caps feature disappears.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that might work for you might be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\begin{document}

{\scshape\itshape i}

{\scshape\bfseries\itshape i}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It's just that the placement of the dots in `i` and `j` with `TeX Gyre Pagella` seem to be a little too low, thus I prefer the result of `TeXGyrePagellaX` used by `newpxtext`, which is similar to that of `Palatino Linotype`. I really hope this issue with `TeXGyrePagellaX` can be fixed some day.

Comment: By the way, I'm also using an up-to-date TeX Live 2022. Are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? This issue is with the OTF file.

Comment: @Jinwen Thank you; I can reproduce it by following the steps correctly. My mistake.