# Numbers in small caps with Palatino Linotype

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I'm using `Palatino Linotype` as my main font, with LuaLaTeX. As you can see from the image below, the numbers in small caps appear to be too small:

[image]

The result using the font `TeXGyrePagellaX` (used by `newpxtext`) seems nice. However, due to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/649525/194994), I cannot use this font for the moment.

[image]

Is there some LuaTeX trick that can fix this problem, making the result similar to that of `TeXGyrePagellaX`?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ Palatino Linotype }
  [
    Numbers = OldStyle ,
    % SmallCapsFeatures = {
    %     Numbers = OldStyle ,
    %     Letters = SmallCaps ,
    % } ,
    % BoldFeatures   = {
    %     SmallCapsFeatures = {
    %         Numbers = OldStyle ,
    %         Letters = SmallCaps ,
    %     } ,
    % } ,
  ]

% \setmainfont { TeXGyrePagellaX }
%   [
%     Extension      = .otf,
%     UprightFont    = *-Regular,
%     BoldFont       = *-Bold,
%     ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
%     BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
%     Numbers = OldStyle ,
%     % SmallCapsFeatures = {
%     %     Numbers = OldStyle ,
%     %     Letters = SmallCaps ,
%     % } ,
%     % BoldFeatures   = {
%     %     SmallCapsFeatures = {
%     %         Numbers = OldStyle ,
%     %         Letters = SmallCaps ,
%     %     } ,
%     % } ,
%   ]

\begin{document}

{\bfseries Abc123}

{\scshape Abc123}

{\bfseries\scshape Abc123}

\end{document}
```

Comment: These are small cap numbers and part of the design, not something to be undone.

Comment: @Thérèse Yes I'm well aware that this is by design but it seems really unnatural. And the purpose of this question is to find a Lua trick to modify this result.

Comment: Not unnatural, but uncommon because found only in fonts of very high quality.